# Topology that induced by uniform structure

Tags: uniform-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space .Calculate the topology induced by uniformity that induced by pseudo metric d ( $U_{d} $)? Is topology induced by metric ?

where $U_d=\{v\subseteq X\times X : v_\epsilon \subseteq v\} $ and $ v_\epsilon =\{(x,y)\in X \times X: d(x,y)< \epsilon \} $

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. $$B_d(x,r)= v_r[x]$$ so both topologies (the uniform one and the metric one) have the same local bases.